# An Induction Problem, What Am I Supposed To Prove?

Tags: induction

I have encountered an induction problem which I don't understand. What I don't understand is what it is asking me to prove. I don't want a solution. The problem is:

If $u_1=5$ and $u_{n+1}=2u_n-3(-1)^n$, then $u_n=3(2^n)+(-1)^n$ for all positive integers.

Am I supposed to prove  $u_{n+1}=2u_n-3(-1)^n$ or $u_n=3(2^n)+(-1)^n$ is true for all positive integers?

Comment: You are supposed to prove that $u_n= 3(2^n)+(-1)^n$. $u_{n+1}=2u_n-3(-1)^n$ is a definition.

Comment: Induction is : [if $P(1)$ and "if $P(n)$, then $P(n+1)$, for every $n$", then "for every $n$, $P(n)$"].

Comment: The expression for $u_n$ is the $P(n)$. First step: is it true that for $n=1$ its value is $5$ ?

Comment: $"\,\color{blue}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{If}}\;u_1=5 \;\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{and}} \;u_{n+1}=2u_n-3(-1)^n}\,, \;\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{ then}}\;u_n=3(2^n)+(-1)^n}\,"\,$ means you are given the blue part, and have to prove the red part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are supposed to prove $u_n=3(2^n)+(-1)^n$.

$u_1=5$ and $u_{n+1}=2u_n-3(-1)^n$ are the conditions you are supposed to make use of.

Answer (score 2):

$u_{n+1}=2u_n-3(-1)^n$ is your recurrence, specifying on how to obtain the $n+1$-st term $u_{n+1}$ from the $n$-th term $u_n$. Together with a start value, $u_1=5$, this stepwise determines the sequence completely.

What the problem is trying to establish, is to show that *in general*, **for any** $n$, you can obtain the $n$-th term directly(without evaluating all $u_k$'s with $k<n$ before) via the formula $u_n=3(2^n)+(-1)^n$. That this formula holds can be shown using induction.

Answer (score 0):

You are given $u_{n+1}=2u_n-3(-1)^n$.  This would allow you to compute the entire series.  For example $$u_2=2u_1-3(-1)^1=2\cdot 5+3=13\\ u_3=2\cdot 13-3(-1)^2=23$$ and so on.  You are supposed to prove the last statement.  It claims
$$u_1=3(2^1)+(-1)^1=5\\u_2=3(2^2)+(-1)^2=13\\u_3=3(2^3)+(-1)^3=23\\\vdots$$

Comment: What do you mean it's incorrect?

Comment: I found my problem.  I had the wrong exponent on the $(-1)^n$